# Using Coroutines in Intent service

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I have a problem with freezing of my application.

So:

1. I have intent service (it is mean all already in another thread)
2. I have a list of users.
3. I should download photos for each user and push them to another cloud service (with face-recognition).

Now we are using a trial version of this service. So it can sends only 10 requests in minute. I want sequential execution of the program (simple version)

But application freeze when it is trying to download user's photos. Only after finishing, application starts work. I hope you understand my explanation.

Here is simple code (I'm using corotinues for it):

```
private val ioScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job())
```

**onCreate method of IntentService**

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    ioScope.launch {
        Repository.getUserList().observeOnce(Observer { users ->
            users?.forEach { user ->
                addedNewUser(user)
            }                
        })
    }
}
```

**addedNewUser**

```
 private suspend fun addedNewUser(user: User) = withTimeoutOrNull(TWO_MINUTES) {
        user.mail ?: return@withTimeoutOrNull

        launch {
            try {
                // withContext is freez place
                val file =  withContext(ioScope.coroutineContext) { getUserAvatar(applicationContext, user.mail) }

                // do something.......

                file.delete()

            } catch (e: ClientException) {      // in free price mode face api allow only 20 requests in minutes
                delay(ONE_MINUTE)
            }
        }.join()
    }
```

Do you have any ideas? Why `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` is freeze?

Also I have tried `withContext(this.coroutineContext)`, but it doesn't wait when file will be downloaded.

Thx, for your time!

**UPDATE (answer)**

Thx everybody, who tried to help me! I think we found the problem. `Repository.getUserList()` - return a `livedata`. So when suspend or runBlocking function started in observer, I watched a freezing. If wraped it in corotinues or new thread it works correctly:

```
    Repository.getUserList().observeOnce(Observer { users ->
        ioScope.launch {
            users?.forEach { user ->
                addedNewUser(user)
            }   
        }.start()
    })
```

Unfortunately I don't know all details how it work under hood, but seems, that observer return value in main thread. So suspend function just stopped main thread.

Comment: **If you are using Crashlytics `GlobalScope.launch{ .. }` will feed up the page with exceptions**. Its recommended to use `CoroutineScope`

Comment: Santanu Sur, thx for mark! I have changed a `GlobalScope` to `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job())` but it doesn't help

Comment: The reason for not using globalscope is you `cannot cancel the job` in `onDestroy` ..so you need to implement.. the `CoroutineScope` .. to the activity

Comment: what's the purpose of the intenservice if you can do the async work with coroutines?

Comment: I'm using intent service because it good practice. Background logic should be work in services. Coroutines is used for synchronization.

Comment: Glad you found solution. Few things I would like to mention. First, I believe it is better to do your job in onHandleIntent method. Second, it feels strange to use LiveData inside coroutine. You may do your work with coroutines and post to LiveData, but not the other way. Use flows or channels to observe such data in service and livedata meant to be observed by views, so it's main thread.